# AUCTeX package missing in emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex, elpa

In my emacs 24.3, I can't find the AUCTeX package.
If I enter PACKAGE-LIST-PACKAGE,
I find various packages for AUCTeX like "auctex-lua" or 
"auto-complete for auctex". However, there is no auctex package that I can install. Why is it gone ?

Comment: AUCTeX is available in the GNU ELPA repository. What does your `package-archives` variable contain?

Comment: I typed in M-x customize-variable [RET] package-archives [RET] and then I see the following:  Archive name: melpa
            URL or directory name: https://melpa.org/packages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUCTeX [is available](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html) via [GNU ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/), not MELPA.

You can configure multiple repositories, e.g. by using `add-to-list` instead of setting `package-archives` directly:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

This should keep GNU ELPA in your list of archives, but in case it doesn't you can always add it back. It should look something like

```
("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
```

Once you've done this you should be able to install AUCTeX via `package.el`.

Note that this is likely the one repository that most users should have in their `package-archives` list. It's the official GNU repository, enabled by default. Of course, feel free to add others as you wish!

Comment: When I add "(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)" to the .emacs file, I get the error message "Symbol's value as variable is void: package-archives"

Comment: I managed to install it though, by just using the elpa line you wrote. However its not working. My 'package-activated-list' says: (auctex auto-compile auto-complete-auctex auto-complete expand-region nnir-est packed dash popup yasnippet). However, when I open a .tex file its only in "(Text fill)" mode

Comment: @Graph4Me, don't you already have a configuration for `package.el` somewhere? Where are you currently configuring MELPA?